# Add service to startup on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu

I need to add a service to the startup on my server.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

update-rc.d servicename defaults

See also [How-To: Managing services with update-rc.d](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-manage-services-with-update-rc.d)

Answer (score 2):

chkconfig [--level levels] service on

ex

chkconfig --level 3,5 httpd on

EDIT : If you don't specify run levels the service will run on all run levels

ie chkconfig httpd on

Comment: That would work for Red Hat based distros, for Ubuntu, best checking the ubuntu forums, things change depending on the version etc: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=212631

Comment: :-\ ..... what are run levels?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel